# Parent ul list items lose hover ability when their child uls are displayed

Tags: css

I have a vertical menu that is transitioning from 0 opacity to 1 just fine.  Everything works except when I hover over a `li` in the 2nd level `ul` I can see the list items from the upper level, but cannot click on them. When I move my cursor off the last `li` to the upper level `li`, the `ul` closes up and the upper level list moves back up.

```html
<div class="accordion">
    <ul>
        <li>My First List Item</li>
        <li>My Second List Item
            <ul>
                <li><a href="http://www.google.com">GOOGLE - 
                                       The first child of my second list item</a></li>
                <li>The second child of my second list item</li>
                <li>The third child of my second list item</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>My Third List Item
                <ul>
                <li>The first child of my third list item</li>
                <li>The second child of my third list item</li>
                <li>The third child of my third list item</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>My Fourth List Item</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="accordionMain"><h3>This is the main content area.</h3>
</div>
```

Now the css:

```
/* This is for the accordion style menu only */
div.accordion{      
    height: 100px;
    width:150px;
    background:darkblue;        
    float:left;             
}
div.accordion ul{               
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;        
    list-style-type:none;       
}
/* LIST ITEMS FROM 1ST LEVEL UL BEFORE LIST IS HOVERED OVER */
div.accordion ul li{        
    position:relative;
    margin:0;
    padding:1px 0px 0px 2px;            
    background-color:pink;                      
}
/* 2ND LEVEL UL BEFORE THE LIST IS HOVERED OVER */
div.accordion ul li ul{
    position:relative;      
}
/* LIST ITEMS FROM THE 2ND LEVEL UL BEFORE LIST IS  HOVERED OVER */
div.accordion ul li ul li{ 
    opacity:0.0;
    -moz-opacity:0.0;
    -o-opacity:0.0;
    -webkit-opacity:0.0;
    height:0px;
    position:relative;/*JUST ADDED 1-8 */       
}
/* 1ST LEVEL LIST ITEMS ON HOVER DO THIS TO THE LIST ITEM*/
div.accordion ul li:hover{
    transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    background-color:lightyellow;
    position:relative;      
}
/* 1ST LEVEL LIST ON HOVER DO THIS TO THE UL FOR THAT LIST ITEM */
div.accordion ul li:hover ul{
    background-color:red;
    z-index:20;/*JUST ADDED LAST */     

}
/* 2ND LEVEL LIST ON HOVER DO THIS TO THE LIST ITEM */
div.accordion ul li ul li:hover{ 
    background-color:fuchsia;       
}
/* 1ST LEVEL LIST ON HOVER DO THIS TO 2ND LEVEL LIST ITEMS */
div.accordion ul li:hover ul li{ 
    background-color:lime;
    height:40px; /* FOR A SMOOTH TRANSITION DO NOT USE AUTO */
    padding-left:15px;
    width:135px;
    border-bottom:1px solid black;
    opacity:1.0;
    -moz-opacity:1.0;
    transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    position:relative;                  
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/SVdGm/

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to do. I noticed that when you mouse from the green menu down to a pink one, the menu jumps - is that the issue? If so, what do you expect to happen? Usually this kind of menu uses clicks instead of just hover, so it isn't an issue. You may need to rethink the design.

Comment: Yes that is the issue.  What I was expecting was that the upper level ul list item would now be clickable, but when the menu jumps back up it is no longer able to be hovered over unless I go up from the bottom.  There is no way to click on the Third List Item unless going from the bottom.  I thought that maybe it might be a problem with height or padding, but after trying every possible combination I could imagine it still won't work.  I am new to CSS menus so am trying to learn a lot.  Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: I just figured it out.  I needed to transition back to a height of 0px after leaving hover on the child list item.  Here is the code I added. div.accordion ul li ul li{
  height: 0px;  
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
 }

Comment: javascript doesn't bite... :)

Answer (score -1):

Nested lists are part of the parent list.  When you hover over the child, you are also hovering over the parent